# RestSharp: Naming the parameter using request.AddJsonBody()?

Tags: json, restsharp

How can I name the piece of multipart/form-data given added to a request when I use the `AddJsonBody()` method?

I am attempting to get past the obsolete `AddParameter()` method.

Here's my code using the `AddJsonBody()` method:

```
request.AddJsonBody(Metadata);
```

There's an overload that allows me to specify the Content-Type, but I just need plain old `application/json` so I'm not using it. Here are the resulting relevant parts of my HTTP request as sent:

```
POST https://redacted/redacted HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------369C5A1F-30CF-450D-A5B4-2DBD93676056

-----------369C5A1F-30CF-450D-A5B4-2DBD93676056
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/json"

{"Date":"2021-07-28T14:27:01.0718841","FurtherInfo":"This is a metadata test."}
-----------369C5A1F-30CF-450D-A5B4-2DBD93676056
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file20210728T1427010660244Z.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

CL7~f`lz4ULMJa;]p-q!uH(-z*4iO'SHD)KYER5SI|e{3zW7^}J,%QPyD)$\K"
[...]
-----------369C5A1F-30CF-450D-A5B4-2DBD93676056--
```

As you can see, the "name" of the added parameter is `application/json`. I want it to be "metadata" instead. So I'm using this code to get things to be sent how I want, but this code is marked as obsolete:

```
Parameter metadata = new Parameter("metadata", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Metadata), "application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter(metadata);
```

Using this changes the HTTP request to:

```
POST https://redacted/redacted HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------8C24DE69-C111-418A-9C29-5D9DFABA320F

-----------8C24DE69-C111-418A-9C29-5D9DFABA320F
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

{
  "date": "2021-07-28T14:45:01.4650889",
  "furtherInfo": "This is a metadata test."
}
-----------8C24DE69-C111-418A-9C29-5D9DFABA320F
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file20210728T1445014611849Z.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

zoRC)Z:c]\<#/z_q,k
[...]
-----------8C24DE69-C111-418A-9C29-5D9DFABA320F--
```

The specific serialization doesn't matter, only that it's valid JSON and has the name `metadata`.

Is there a way to use the newer `AddJsonBody()` method to do this? Is manipulating the parameter name on the roadmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

From [the class definition of RestRequest](https://restsharp.dev/api/RestSharp.html#class-restrequest):

```
public IRestRequest AddParameter(string name, object value, string contentType, ParameterType type)
```

Instead of creating the Parameter, I can just add the parameter directly:

```
request.AddParameter("metadata", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Metadata), "application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

And no more obsolete warning!

Answer (score 0):

as my understanding you are trying to send a file?
thi sis an example to send a file to API using RestSharp

```
using (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest("/api/Upload", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request.AddParameter("ServiceID", ServiceID, ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("Description", description, ParameterType.QueryString);

        //get byte[] , in reallife would be a stream
        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes($@"C:\1\TEST\{filename}");
        request.AddFileBytes("DocumentFile", fileData, filename, "multipart/form-data");

        var result = client.Execute(request).Dump();
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to send two things--a JSON object called "metadata" and a file in the same request. The file is working fine, but the additional metadata is getting a "name" of "application/json" when I want it to be named "metadata".

Comment: try on metadata parameter  type: ParameterType.QueryString, try to use Fidler to see request

Comment: I am using Fiddler, and it has to be in the body as part of the multipart/form-data.

Comment: in this case use request and set object. dont serialize:
var request = new RestRequest("/api/SET_XXX", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json).AddJsonBody(CLASS);